# trivlist list environment \item command

Tags: macros, lists, ntheorem, paralist

My document class uses `paralist` and redefines `\begin{enumerate}[(a)][abc]` etc... environments to issue `\label` for each `\item`, given a second option (e.g., `\abc{a}`) that becomes a 1-parameter macro issuing `\ref`. For this both `\@item` and `\pl@item` are "*overloaded*".

However, there is a problem with, e.g., `ntheorem` environment nested inside `enumerate`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)][abc] % \ref{...} is the body of "\gdef\abc" in refined
  \item one
    \begin{theorem}[second]
      ... and so it follows. 
    \end{theorem}
\end{enumerate}

As in the point \abc*{1} above... % starred wraps around parentheses
```

I found `ntheorem` (and many other environments) use `trivlist` for style; so the example above is troublesome because there is an extra `\item` issued, without `\@listdepth` increased.

I have actually to switch between `\let\@item\old@item` and `\let@item\new@item` accordingly with my redefined `\begin|\end{enumerate}`, because from "`new`" I also generate `\label` commands, for each `\item` issued.

```
\let\old@item\@item
\gdef\@item[#1]{\old@item[#1] ...}
\let\new@item\@item
\let\old@pl@item\pl@item
\def\pl@item[#1]{\old@pl@item[#1] ...}
\let\new@pl@item\pl@item
```

But the `\trivlist` from `ntheorem` gives "multiple defined labels" because of the "*spurious*" `\item` coming with `\trivlist`.

Next try was to redefine `\@trivlist` (also `\endtrivlist`),

```
\def\@trivlist{\if@newlist ... \fi}
```

where the dots in `\@trivlist` keep track of whether

```
\def\endtrivlist{\if@newlist ... \fi}
```

the dots in `\endtrivlist` should restore either the `old` or the `new` `\@item` and `\pl@item` (re)definitions.

There is, though, never the case that `\@newlist` conditional is true, and `\trivlist` is heavily used everywhere: thus, I fail to discern the case of list environmens (that enumerate are too), from... `\everypar`?

Initially, my intent was to intercept `\@thm` and `\@endtheorem`, but I tried widening the possibilities of environments nested in redefined `\begin{enumerate}`, and this is how I ran over `\trivlist`.

The problem is that `\@trivlist` occurs many times **not paired** by `\endtrivlist`, which makes my task impossible (since I employ a push/pop technique). And trying using `\if@newlist`, supposedly suggesting that a list (always paired) is involved, the code is skipped, the flag is `false`. That not enough, `\@trivlist` also tests the flag `\if@inlabel`, having something to do with just *after* `\item`, while I must take care of `old/new` trick *before* `\item`.

Appreciate any help,
Thank s.

Comment: Please, add a complete minimal example.

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to globally change the meaning of `\item`

Comment: Ok, it would seem I should add an ME.

Answer (score 7):

`\endtrivlist` should be paired with `\trivlist` (rather than `\@trivlist`) despite the name including the letters `l i s t` the trivlist mechanism should be seen as the basic display environment mechanism in LaTeX. It is used for all kinds of display environment that would not normally be considered lists, such as `center`, `verbatim`, `tabbing`. You really don't want to mess with `\trivlist` unless you want to redefine everything.

Comment: Yes, it should, not by my code, though, I don't *use*, I only try to keep track of alternating nested hierarchies of "enumerate" environments from `paralist` however mixed with other list environments, e.g., `ntheorem`. My question concerned what can I do with unexpected behavior of `\trivlist`, since I depend on `\@trivlist`/`\endtrivlist` to come in pair, I do not want to change them, I hook them.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the snippets of a possible MWE you've provided, I'm thinking the following might be along the lines of what you want.  Instead of redefining LaTeX commands, I've created a new environment `myenum` and a *pseudo* `\item` that I call with `\myitem`.  This way there should be no conflicts with other definitions relying upon LaTeX's definitions.

I use `xparse` to create an environment with two optional arguments (since your code seems to indicate that that's what you want) and their default behaviors.  Though if you omit the second and then later omit both, LaTeX will be unhappy about multiply defined labels.  There seem to be two reasonable choices here (1) change the order of the arguments (2) force one of them to be mandatory.

You also seem to want your second argument to define a command to call the particular reference and a *starred* version to apply parentheses around the reference.  Here's a MWE that does that while also making the second argument mandatory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
%%
\makeatletter
%% create a command to assign an enum-based prefix for each label
\newcommand{\my@label@prefix}{unused}
%% allows a starred version for the reference to have parentheses.
\newcommand{\my@ref}[2]{\ref{#1:#2}}
\newcommand{\my@@ref}[2]{(\my@ref{#1}{#2})}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenum}{ O{(a)} m }
    {\renewcommand{\my@label@prefix}{#2}%
     %% check whether second argument corresponds to pre-existing command!
     \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #2\endcsname%
        {\global\@namedef{#2}{\@ifstar{\my@@ref{#2}}{\my@ref{#2}}}}%
     \begin{enumerate}[#1]}
    {\end{enumerate}}
%% This next line uses paralist's internal
%% `\pl@the` to pass the correct label mark.
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item\label{\my@label@prefix:\pl@the}}
%% \newcommand{\myitem}{\item\label{\my@label@prefix:\alph{enumi}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent%
First:
\begin{myenum}[(a)]{abc}
  \myitem one
    \begin{theorem}\label{thm:first}
      ... and so it follows. 
    \end{theorem}
  \myitem two
\end{myenum}
Second (\abc{a}):
\begin{myenum}[(A)]{xyz}
  \myitem one
    \begin{theorem}\label{thm:second}
      ... and so it follows. 
    \end{theorem}
  \myitem two
\end{myenum}
Third:
\begin{myenum}[(i)]{getit}
  \myitem one
  \myitem two
  \myitem three
  \myitem four
  \myitem five
\end{myenum}

\textbf{From first:} As in the point \ref{abc:a} and \abc{b} above... 

\textbf{From second:} As in the point \ref{xyz:A} and \xyz*{B} above... 

\textbf{From third:} As in the point \getit*{iv} and \getit{iii} above... 

\textbf{Theorems:} The first theorem is \ref{thm:first} and the second is \ref{thm:second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems a bit contrary to LaTeX to define labels in a manner that depends upon a particular order.  But also, that seemed to be what you wanted and I can imagine situations where that might be desirable (just not many).

Comment: Thanks for your viable answer. I already have implemented  all four `\begin{asparaenum}`, `\begin{inparaenum}`, `\begin{compactenum}`, `\begin{enumerate}`: `myenum` and `\myitem` are out of the question; `\label` is issued (hierarchically, with possible lists of item refs or "numbers") for all five representations: alph, Alph, roman, Roman, arabic, so that users make no mistake however they like to reference `\item`s. Users *must* only use known `LaTeX`. My question is not about what I have already coded. Avoiding `\item` by `\myitem` is unacceptable. It was really fast your solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `\begin{enumerate}` vs `\end{enumerate}` *always* come in pair, and the *only* obvious connection with other "list" environments are the `\begin` vs `\end` "commands", hooking them by redefinition, employing only one redefinition of `\@item` and `\pl@item` throughout the document but using a `\boolean` flag to condition the actually **needed** side-effect upon issuing `\item` (i.e., generate `\label` commands), together at last with a stack-like "`\GetTokens` vs `\@removeelement`" implemented list... seems the best-fit trick there is.

The `\trivlist` vs `\endtrivlist` proved indeed an impossible MWE trial&error direction.

The missing MWE would have taken too much "moving out of the context" effort; instead, i failed with an "unbalanced" attempt like basing on the first `\item` occurrence (following the idea from `\if@newlist`) for "push" paired with `\endtrivlist` for "pop".

```
\let\my@begin\begin
\def\begin{%\my@push{either true or false}{into the stack} depending on flag
           %set flag false
           \my@begin}

\let\my@end\end
\def\begin{%\my@pop{into \my@temp}{from the stack} and set flag to \my@temp 
           \my@end}

%\let\my@enum\---macro missing---
%redefined \begin{enumerate}: invoke \my@enum; set flag true; ...

\let\my@item\@item
\gdef\@item[#1]{\my@item[#1]%
                %trigger generate \label only if flag and ...%
                }

\let\my@pl@item\pl@item
\def\pl@item[#1]{\my@pl@item[#1]%
                 %trigger generate \label only if flag and ...%
                }
```

s.