# Little indentation despite \noindent after tabu custom-environment

Tags: tables, spacing, environments, indentation, tabu

this question is about a (to me) mysterious little indent (looks like an ordinary blank...) after a custom-environment using the `tabu`-environment.

Please compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]{
            \par\centering
            \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{tabu}\par\noindent}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}
%
HERE HAPPENS INDENT\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

Following the answers from similar questions I put `%` into the blank lines and `\noindent` works fine here. However, there is this little blank-like indentation of the paragraph after the table.

I figured out that I can make it disappear when adding a `%` after the `\end` part in the text, so:

```
<table content> \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}% (!)
%
NOINDENT THIS TIME...
```

---

Please explain; how is this? Can I somehow include the solution into the definition of the environment or is it necessary to put that `%` everytime I use this environment?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that the newline after the environment acts as a space is because you have used `\noindent` which is prematurely putting TeX in horizontal mode so as always in that mode ends of lines produce word spaces.

You can counteract that by going

```
            {\end{tabu}\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
```

But this is really the wrong way to do things, having `\noindent` there means that you can not have a blank line after the environment or you get a spurious white paragraph. Note you needed `%` before `HERE`

All LaTeX display environments handle suppressing indentation, just use

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]{
            \begin{center}%
            \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{tabu}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}
%
HERE HAPPENS INDENT\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Then you will get no indentation for `HERE` if there is no blank line before it, but if you do have a blank line because in some cases you want to start a paragraph there, you will get indentation.

Comment: Hmm, I already had a solution using `center`-environment, however, when I use `longtabu` there comes [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115180/vertical-spaces-above-and-below-longtabu?rq=1) problem with spacing which I tried to avoid by using `\centering`. It seems I have to use `center` or place that ominous `%`, which is, as you say, not a "nice way"...?

Comment: @LCsa You can use a list environment with the vertical spacing sent to 0 rather than the default center environment (ie set `\parsep`, `\partopsep` to 0pt)

Comment: I don't understand... Why a `list`-environment?

Comment: the list environment is mis-named, it is not (just) for making lists it is the generic latex display environment base, in particular for handling this indentation issue, center, flushright, verbatim, tabbing are all (triv)list environments see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/why-is-the-quote-environment-defined-as-a-list  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89633/trivlist-list-environment-item-command/89637#89637

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere inside `tabu` there is a sporadic space or a  missing `\ignorespaces` or `\ignorespacesafterend`

Adding \ignorespaces right after `\end{texttab}` seems to work

Comment: Well, this has the same effect as the `%`... Any idea about a solution to embed in the definition of the environment (preamble)?
I tried to place `\noindent` at various places there - to no avail.

Comment: No idea, `\noindent` will never work as it is not indentation that is the problem.

Comment: It is the `\noindent` that is causing the space to appear:-)